# Cannot get psql command to run in bash script

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I'm a bit of a novice at bash scripting, so bear with me. I'm trying to write a script to execute a sql file using `psql`. From my terminal, it works fine:

`psql -f /path/to/file.sql "$URI"`

However, in my script I have something like this:

```
dbURI="postgres://some.connection.string"
psql -f /path/to/file.sql $dbURI
```

But I keep getting output like this:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I cannot seem to get this to work at all. I've tried wrapping the variable in quotes, using `$(command)`, etc, with no luck.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: So, did you start your Postgres server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Yes.

Comment: Are you connecting to localhost or an alias of localhost?

Comment: What do you mean with "from my terminal it works fine" - where do you run that script if not in "your terminal"? And what is the connection string that you use on "your terminal" and what is the connection string that you use on the terminal where it doesn't work? You are clearly specifying a hostname where no Postgres instance is running

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name let's not be pedantic. When I ran the `psql` command with the connection string from terminal, it works. Yes, obviously the bash script runs in the terminal. Also, you are incorrect in your assumption. It obviously does work because I can echo the string and connect via direct terminal `psql` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below in your script to disable globbing

```
psql -f /path/to/file.sql "$dbURI"
```

Comment: That's a sane recommendation, but if the URI in the question is representative, this is in no way going to resolve their problem.

Comment: The OP mentioned that the command works ok when run directly form the terminal (using the double quotes), but id does not from inside a script (without the double quotes) so I guess the obvious first step is to try it with the double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem, with the exact same error message. The problem was that Postgresql takes a few seconds to start. So, if it is the case that you start postgresql and use a psql command in the same script, chances are that postgre has not yet started when you call it.

The solution was to include:

```
sleep 5
```

before the psql command. In your case, this would be:

```
sleep 5
psql -f /path/to/file.sql "$URI"
```

This gives some time for postgre to start before you use it.

I see the topic is 2 years old, but in case anyone else faces the same problem.